# External Application accessing a Sharepoint Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, asp.net, mvc, front-end, database-server

I have a specific scenario, wherein I have an application built ASP.net MVC accessing a SharePoint server.

Now my SharePoint server has a configuration where there are 2 Web Front End servers and 2 Database servers clustered.

The Web Front End servers are using a load balancer.

Now I want to host my External ASP.net web application.

Can I host my application on one of the Web Front End server?

Or I will have to have another server which will host my application?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to host your second Web App on your WFE servers.  I am currently doing this on my farm and I have no issues.  My second App is custom SAML STS for my SharePoint. 
 A thing to think about might be you will have to account for you patching and update schedule on your WFE with your secondary app.  Your availability is now the same as your SharePoint WFE.